# Search results for term query not in alphabetical sort order

Tags: elasticsearch

My results for the following term query gets rendered like this. But we would want the search results where "BC" appears after "Bar", since we are trying to perform a alphabetical search. What should be done to get this working

> ```
> Adam
> Buck
> BC
> Bar
> Car
> Far
> ```

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes().build())
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("type", field))
    .withSort(new FieldSortBuilder("name").order(SortOrder.ASC))
    .withPageable(pageable).build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the result in alphabetical order you can define a normalizer with a lowercase filter, lowercase filter will ensure that all the letters are changed to lowercase before indexing the document and searching.

Modify your index mapping as

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexed the same sample documents as given in the question.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "sort":{
    "name":{
      "order":"asc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Adam"
        },
        "sort": [
          "adam"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Bar"
        },
        "sort": [
          "bar"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "BC"
        },
        "sort": [
          "bc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Buck"
        },
        "sort": [
          "buck"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Car"
        },
        "sort": [
          "car"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064809",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Far"
        },
        "sort": [
          "far"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```